# Fetching Specific Data from Database in Controller Function

Tags: php, symfony

I’m a total noob at Symphony but I’m trying to learn. The documentation has not been able to help me with this specific problem I’m having.

How can I do something like this:

```
// if ($products are in userCart) {
//     show those only
// }
```

I’m struggling with finding a way to get that information. I’ve tried many attempts.

I am successfully flushing my products to the database and my associations are as follows:

[Association Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z50lv.png)

I want to do this in `showCartAction` function:

```
$user = $this->getUser();
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

//then get the specific products

$products = $em->getRepository(‘ShopBundle:??’)->??
```

Please any help is appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the entity is named `Product`:

```
// Your model, you can use it to fetch products
$productRepository = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:Product');

// Retrieve all products as an array of objects
$products = $productRepository->findAll();

// Retrieve a specific product as object from its reference (id)
$product = $productRepository->find(1); // Returns product with 'id' = 1

// Retrieve a specific product based on condition(s)
$product = $productRepository->findOneBy(['price' => 10]);

// Retrieve many products based on condition(s)
$products = $productRepository->findBy(['price' => 10]);
```

To check if a specific product is in your `UserCart` object:

```
$cartRepository = $em->getRepository('ShopBundle:UserCart');

// Fetches the cart by its owner (the current authenticated user)
// assuming UserCart has a $user property that represents an association to your User entity
$cart = $cartRepository->findOneBy(['user' => $this->getUser()]);

// Check if a specific product is in the cart,
// assuming $product is a Product object retrieved like shown above
if ($cart->contains($product)) {
    // Do something
}
```

For the whole reference, see [Working with objects](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html) from Doctrine documentation.

I hope that will help you.
Do not hesitate to post a comment if you need more precisions or any other information.

**EDIT**

To access properties of an object, use its getters:

```
$cartView = array(
    'products' => $cart->getProducts(), // return the property $products
    'user'     => $cart->getUser(),     // return the property $user
);
```

That is possible only if the methods exist and have public access.

**Note** You should really look more at OOP and practice it before use a framework like Symfony.

Comment: This is very good but `$cart` when I print is still an object. I want it to print what's inside of the cart. I hope I am being understood. I will make an edit to show

Comment: Look at my edit. I show you how access the properties of your object.

Comment: Thank You very much, I will work and touch back later

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer that solves your problem, if there is one, it's the better thanks that you can give, and will surely help people with the same issue.

Comment: I'm almost there I think but how can I instead do `$cartRepo = $em->getRepository('PascalShopTestBundle:Quantity');`      `$cart = $cartRepo->findOneBy(['userCart' => $cartRepo->getUserCart()]);`?

Comment: How do you want that cartRepository->getUserCart() (or anything else) could work? A Repository is not an entity, it doesn't have any property. You can use getters of an object only after retrieved it. You should really take the time to learn OOP, how an ORM works and how it can interact with a framework. The repository is only your Model, nothing more. It allows you to fetch entries of a specific entity. I can't help you anymore as your logic is totally wrong. Sorry!